# How to en/decode Base64 string from Java that has unsigned bytes in C# that has signed bytes?

Tags: java, c#, base64, byte

A byte array in Java of the length of 8 with values `Byte.MIN_VALUE`:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
Arrays.fill(bytes, Byte.MIN_VALUE);
// [-127, -127, -127, -127, -127, -127, -127, -127]
string base64string = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
```

when I encode this byte array into Base64, it results into: `gICAgICAgIA=`

However, when C# decodes this array, it results into `[128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128]`, because C#'s byte is unsigned. **Expected result should be** `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

C#'s byte array of `byte.MinValue` results in the Base64 string `AAAAAAAAAAA=` and Java decodes this Base64 string into `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` instead of the expected result `[-127, -127, -127, -127, -127, -127, -127, -127]`.

The decoding in C# is done with `Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)`.

Is there a way to convert Java's bytes into unsigned ones and encode them in Base64 so that C# can decode them correctly? Or is there a way for C#  to convert Java's Base64 encoded byte array of unsigned bytes into a Base64 encoded byte array of signed bytes?

I also should mention, that I want also to be able to encode C#'s byte array into Base64 that is correctly readable in Java.

Comment: _"Expected result should be ..."_ Why it's expected?

Comment: Java's byte ranges from -128 to 127, making the value -128 the minimum one. C#'s byte ranges from 0 to 256, making the value 0 the minimum one. For compatibility's sake, C#'s decoded byte array should consist of zeroes, to hold the same information as Java's byte array.

Comment: *C#'s byte ranges from 0 to 256,*,  Nope, it goes from `0 to 255 inclusive`.  `256 is a 9 bit value.`. 
 On most architectures, bytes are eight bits, signed or unsigned.    No byte array with the high order bit set should result in an all zero array when base64 decoded   It sounds like you are expecting some sort of overflow of -127  or 128 resulting in 0.

Comment: "*convert Java's bytes into unsigned ones*" -- what value should `-127` be converted to? to zero? And what should zero be converted to?

Comment: *I also should mention, that I want also to be able to encode C#'s byte array into Base64 that is correctly readable in Java.* The only thing that would make it *incorrect* would be to interpret the bit pattern incorrectly. That means you must (if you want the same *values* as C#) *unsign* each element with `element & 0xFF`. The same principal applies in the opposite direction

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [sbyte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types).

Answer (score 1):

The encoded string "gICAgICAgIA=" stands for binary "10000000 10000000 10000000 10000000 10000000 10000000 10000000 10000000". https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-binary

Binary 10000000 = -128 (For signed byte) and 10000000 = 128 (For unsigned byte). In .NET Byte is unsigned and SByte is type for Signed Byte. Ranges are identical to Java.

Use sbyte[] instead of byte[]. Byte is 8-bit unsigned integer with range of 0 to 255 while sbyte is 8-bit signed integer with range from -128 to 127.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var x = Convert.FromBase64String("gICAgICAgIA=");
        // Print as Signed Bytes
        foreach(var sb in x)
        {
            Console.Write($"{(SByte)sb} ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        // Print as Unsigned Bytes
        foreach(var b in x)
        {
            Console.Write($"{b} ");
        }
    }
}
```

And the output is

```
-128 -128 -128 -128 -128 -128 -128 -128 
128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128
```

Answer (score 0):

The results are coherent:

```
Java: Byte.MIN_VALUE = -128, binary representation: '10000000' 
C#:   byte.MinValue  = 0   , binary representation: '00000000'
```

You cannot expect the same base 64 string. Somewhere, you lack a translation between the two different types you are using.